# Running a powershell script BeforeBuild to modify web.config - how?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, powershell

I have a standard C# MVC web project with a `web.config`.  What I'd like to do (please don't dig into the intentions here - it's a long story) - is run a powershell script (or executable, less preferably) to modify the contents of the web.config before building.

I've noticed the `BeforeBuild` section of my csproj file, but I don't know how to leverage this to run a script against my web.config.  Is this possible?

Comment: Do you know about SlowCheetah? https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5

Comment: Yes.  `please don't dig into the intentions here`

Comment: https://davidfrette.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/creating-powershell-pre-build-and-post-build-events-for-visual-studio-projects/

Comment: @DavidBrabant was just going to post the same one heh